# JavaScript error: "The resource was realized on the wrong render target"

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro, runtime-error

I am developing a Windows 8 app with JavaScript.
The app seems to work fine but sometimes during runtime I get the error message: "JavaScript error: The resource was realized on the wrong render target".
The error comes from a preloader called "Canvas Loader".

Does anyone knows what this error means? How to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you listed is a Direct2D error message:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370979(v=vs.85).aspx

It seems very strange you're getting this from manipulating a JavaScript canvas. I almost wonder if there's a graphics driver issue going on here. Have you been able to reproduce it on other machines?